# Nodejs How to combine specific row if it is redundant?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to filter out the non-unique values in an array and combine it using javascript?

This is the sample array

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "description": "dddd ",
      "section": "Apple"

  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "description": "ddd",
      "section": "Apple"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "name": "aaa",
      "section": "orange"
  }
]
```

what i want result is

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "description": "dddd, ddd",
      "section": "Apple"

  },

  {
      "id": 2,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "name": "aaa",
      "section": "orange"
  }
]
```

How to filter out the non-unique values in an array and combine it using javascript?How to filter out the non-unique values in an array and combine it using javascript?How to filter out the non-unique values in an array and combine it using javascript?

Comment: Based on the output data,if `section` are the same and mark them as duplicate?

Comment: @flyingfox, YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it via [**Array.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let data = [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "description": "dddd ",
      "section": "Apple"

  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "description": "ddd",
      "section": "Apple"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "CreatedDate": "2022-07-15 16:08",
      "name": "aaa",
      "section": "orange"
  }
]

let result = data.reduce((a,c) =>{
  let obj = a.find(i => i.section === c.section)
  if(obj){
    obj.description += " / " + c.description
  }else{
    c.id = a.length + 1 // reset the id
    a.push(c) 
  }
  return a
},[])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What if I want to display it to array instead of string?

Comment: @denise Then make `description` an array